# performance counters library on ubuntu in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance, linux-kernel

I am trying to find some library for accessing performance counter in ubuntu. But I am not able to find it. In linux website I have found about pmc.h library. But I am not able to find it in my system. Can someone help me to find some library to retrieve performance counters data?

I am using ubuntu 11 and i386 processor. Another strange thing I observed in my ubuntu is, I am not able to find /usr/include/sys directory. This is required for me to use socket.h :(

Answer (score 4):

1. I'm not aware about *pmc* (seems like it exists only for Darwin?), but consider using [libpfm](http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/):

   ```
   sudo apt-cache search libpfm
   ```
2. `/usr/include/socket.h` belongs to *libc6-dev*:

   ```
   dpkg -L libc6-dev | grep socket.h
   ```

   Install *libc6-dev* via:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
   ```

Comment: Thanks Andrejs, socket.h problem resolved. Now, I am just hoping for performance counters problem resolution

Comment: "sudo apt-cache search libpfm" is not displaying anything.  :(

Comment: Hmm, true.. Oneiric (Ubuntu 11) does not have this package (yet?): http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpfm&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all

Comment: Anyway, nothing stops you building it from the sources.